# Is the usage of "I couldn't tell X apart" correct?

Tags: expressions, sentence

Example:

> The forest was dark and the trees too many. I could hardly **tell shadows apart.**

Is the usage of *apart* correct in the passage above?

(I'm wondering about this because a Google Books search returned only [one](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22guts%20all%20over%20the%20place%22#q=%22tell%20shadows%20apart%22&tbm=bks) result).

Comment: Try searching for "tell the shadows apart". Your use of *apart* is fine.

Comment: You may perhaps understand the sentence better if we modify it a bit.  _The forest was dark and the trees too many. I could hardly tell shadows apart from the trees._

Comment: @JayHook What I meant was: "I can't tell the shadows apart from each other."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything inherently ungrammatical about your example but it is *slightly* confusing:

> I could hardly tell shadows apart.

Apart from what? Other shadows? Trying to tell shadows apart from other shadows is *always* difficult. Any alternatives would depend on the specific context but it may help to clarify the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

That's an absolutely valid usage. [Check out the meaning of this idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tell+things+apart)